# Как писать простенькие приложения для Android, используя яп Python?

Tags: android, python, apk

Тратить огромное кол-во времени на изучение java, для написания простеньких бот-программ считаю не лучшим решением

Comment: Вы можете найти множество материалов по данному вопросу в поисковиках по запросу «developing android apps with python». Это решение лучшим я не считаю, но если Вы так хотите.

Comment: Если интерфейс сложнее уведомлений нафиг не нужен, то посоветую Termux: даёт Debian-подобное окружение в терминале, позволяя сделать `apt-get install python` и дальше юзать его как в любом обычном линуксе (или макоси, благо одинаково)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python-for-android
Прежде всего давайте посмотрим на то, с помощью чего Python получает возможность работать под Android — инструмент, названный, как ни странно, python-for-android. Его основная функция состоит в том, чтобы создать дистрибутив — папку проекта, содержащую все необходимое для запуска вашего приложения. А точнее, сам интерпретатор, Kivy и библиотеки, от которых он зависит: Pygame, SDL и несколько других. Также дистрибутив включает в себя загрузчик Java, отображающий OpenGL и выступающий в качестве посредника между Kivy и операционной системой. Затем вы добавляете ко всему этому свои скрипты, настройки вроде иконки и имени, компилируете с помощью Android NDK и вуаля — APK с вашим приложением готов!

И это всего лишь базовая процедура, на самом деле сгенерированный пакетный файл может включать (и включает) в себя гораздо больше. Вместе со всем прочим в APK вшивается большая часть стандартной библиотеки, а любой сторонний модуль, написанный на Python, может быть легко добавлен — все так же, как и при разработке десктоп-приложений. Добавка модулей с компилируемыми компонентами тоже не вызывает трудностей, необходимо лишь указать, как их нужно собирать. Как правило, это не представляет собой ничего сложного, достаточно лишь поставить пару галочек перед запуском процедуры сборки, хотя в редких отдельных случаях могут понадобиться дополнительные действия. Python-for-android уже включает в себя указания для компиляции таких популярных модулей, как: numpy, sqlite3, twisted и даже django!

Вышеописанные принципы лишь в общих словах объясняют, как работает python-for-android. В любой момент вы можете получить больше информации на данную тему, заглянув в документацию Kivy. Я рекомендую вам Buildozer — надстройку для python-for-android, предоставляющую собой удобный интерфейс и автоматическое разрешение некоторых зависимостей. Мы стараемся сделать так, чтобы написанная выше цепочка действий использовалась не только в Kivy, но и в других проектах. Основной процесс сборки останется таким же, но нужда в загрузчике Java отпадет, так как он необходим только для поддержки некоторых специфичных нужд фреймворка.

Обращение к Android API с помощью PyJNIus
Взаимодействие с Android API: получение информации с сенсоров, создание уведомлений, вибрация, пауза и перезапуск, да что угодно — важная часть вашего приложения. Kivy за вас позаботится об основном, но многими вещами вы захотите управлять сами. Для этого создан PyJNIus — инструмент, автоматически оборачивающий код на Java в интерфейс Python.

В качестве простого примера приведем программу, которая заставит телефон вибрировать на протяжении 10 секунд:

```
from jnius import autoclass
# Для начала нам нужна ссылка на Java Activity, в которой
# запущено приложение, она хранится в загрузчике Kivy PythonActivity
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
vibrator = activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)
vibrator.vibrate(10000)  # аргумент указывается в миллисекундах
```

Если вы знакомы с Android API, то без труда заметите, что код выше очень похож на аналогичный на Java — PyJNIus просто позволяет нам обращаться к тому же API, но прямо из Python. Большая часть Android API может быть вызвана подобным образом, что позволяет достичь того же функционала, что и при разработке на Java.

Главный минус PyJNIus в том, что он требует неплохого понимания структуры Android API, а код выходит громоздким, хотя его эквивалент на Java выглядит точно так же. Для решения этой проблемы Kivy включает в себя Plyer.

Plyer: кроссплатформенное API для платформоспецифичных задач
Проект Plyer ставит себе цель создать простой «питоничный» интерфейс для функций, которые присутствуют на большинстве платформ. Например, код выше легким движением руки превращается в…

```
from plyer.vibrator import vibrate
vibrate(10)  # В Plyer аргументы указываются в секундах
```

Более того, написанный код попытается выполнить свою задачу на всех поддерживаемых Plyer платформах — на данный момент это: Android, iOS, Linux, Windows и OS X (для iOS также существует аналог PyJNIus, называемая PyOBJus). На самом деле, вибрация — не самый лучший пример, потому что сейчас она реализована только для Android, но такие функции как проверка уровня заряда батареи:

```
from plyer import battery; print(battery.status)
```

или text-to-speech:

```
from plyer import tts; tts.speak('hello world')
```

— работают как в десктопных, так и в мобильных приложениях, а получение данных с компаса/гироскопа и отправка SMS без проблем реализуются на Android и iOS.

Plyer находится на начальной стадии развития, так что любая помощь в разработке приветствуется. Также, мы участвуем с ним в Google Summer of Code в этом году.

Не только ради Kivy
Все вышеперечисленные инструменты были разработаны для нашего фреймворка, но на самом деле они больше предназначены для разработки под Python в целом. В Plyer мы специально избегаем какой-либо зависимости от Kivy, а PyJNIus нужен лишь для доступа к Android JNI. Искренне надеемся, что эти инструменты станут полезны для любого, кто пишет на Python под Android. Вы уже можете попробовать PyJNIus, используя QPython. Python-for-android больше завязан на взаимодействии с Kivy, но мы будем рады обсудить этот вопрос.

Многое можно реализовать при разработке на Android с помощью Python, несмотря на все различия с Java, которая предназначена для этого, но эти возможности могут быть расширены еще больше в ближайшем будущем. И если вы заинтересовались описанными выше проектами, то самое время присоединиться к нашей команде!

Оригинальная статья "[Kivy Planet](https://kivy.org/planet/2015/04/python-on%C2%A0android/)"
Русский источник "[Как разрабатывать на Python под Android](https://tproger.ru/translations/python-development-on-android/)"

Comment: Вы забыли указать ссылку на первоисточник ;)

Comment: @s8am точно. Добавил